# Appending Rows to the file already existing in Azure Data Factory - Mapping Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have mapping data flow pipeline in ADF which will take the input file , transform it and then stores the data in CSV format in storage account for each day with day in the name of the file. The input file also has the day in the file name.
The Input file for a particular day can be updated. so the output file should be updated accordingly.

The issue what i am facing the where there is an update to the input file, the output is only having the updated information, the old values are getting replaced.

Is there any way where ever the data pipeline runs and it checks on the storage account if the file exists it appends the new records.

Comment: To append, you would need to read the entire contents of the target file into memory first in your data flow. Set a Source transform that points to the file you wish to append to and then Union it with the new incoming data to append.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Get Metadata activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) to check whether the file exists.

Then you can use [Union transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-union) to append incoming data.

---

**Update**

You can do something like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. But i cannot use metadata activity in mapping data flow.